# Reorder objects in array based on one of their string properties?

Tags: javascript

Currently, I am receiving an array with 3 objects from an API GET request but I want to reorder the objects based on one of their properties.

For example, I want the object with property `queueType: "RANKED_SOLO_5x5"` to become the first element in the array and the second object with property `queueType: "RANKED_TFT"` to become the second element and in case there more than 2 objects, any ordering is fine for the rest of them, I just want the first 2 elements to be the ones with properties `queueType: "RANKED_SOLO_5x5"` and `queueType: "RANKED_TFT"`

Can this be done?

This is the object I'm getting from the API on 1 user:

```
[
  {
    "rank": "IV",
    "tier": "PLATINUM",
    "wins": 17,
    "losses": 116,
    "veteran": false,
    "inactive": false,
    "leagueId": "e62390f0-aad4-11e9-9332-c81f66dd0e0d",
    "hotStreak": false,
    "queueType": "RANKED_TFT",
    "freshBlood": false,
    "summonerId": "TUCyI-h1s6ZJBNiag9c9ZBIkFxBCeP6Yn7i8GpHeuhYPI-Y",
    "leaguePoints": 23,
    "summonerName": "The Onyx King"
  },
  {
    "rank": "IV",
    "tier": "PLATINUM",
    "wins": 312,
    "losses": 318,
    "veteran": true,
    "inactive": false,
    "leagueId": "000d4c70-767a-11e9-9acb-c81f66dacb22",
    "hotStreak": false,
    "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
    "freshBlood": false,
    "summonerId": "TUCyI-h1s6ZJBNiag9c9ZBIkFxBCeP6Yn7i8GpHeuhYPI-Y",
    "leaguePoints": 0,
    "summonerName": "The Onyx King"
  }
]
```

This is the object I get on another one:

```
[
  {
    "rank": "II",
    "tier": "GOLD",
    "wins": 634,
    "losses": 694,
    "veteran": true,
    "inactive": false,
    "leagueId": "af7c0330-99f8-11e9-a190-c81f66db01ef",
    "hotStreak": false,
    "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
    "freshBlood": false,
    "summonerId": "z7n0ZG97hF5_wbOvDRwv2dk05STsdRO2ed4thi7dKl7yEfA",
    "leaguePoints": 53,
    "summonerName": "Chazmie"
  },
  {
    "rank": "II",
    "tier": "SILVER",
    "wins": 51,
    "losses": 64,
    "veteran": false,
    "inactive": false,
    "leagueId": "bd777110-b530-11e9-92ba-c81f66dacb22",
    "hotStreak": false,
    "queueType": "RANKED_FLEX_SR",
    "freshBlood": false,
    "summonerId": "z7n0ZG97hF5_wbOvDRwv2dk05STsdRO2ed4thi7dKl7yEfA",
    "leaguePoints": 12,
    "summonerName": "Chazmie"
  },
  {
    "rank": "IV",
    "tier": "SILVER",
    "wins": 5,
    "losses": 36,
    "veteran": false,
    "inactive": false,
    "leagueId": "6b7f3610-acc3-11e9-9ce9-c81f66db01ef",
    "hotStreak": false,
    "queueType": "RANKED_TFT",
    "freshBlood": true,
    "summonerId": "z7n0ZG97hF5_wbOvDRwv2dk05STsdRO2ed4thi7dKl7yEfA",
    "leaguePoints": 11,
    "summonerName": "Chazmie"
  }
]
```

As you can see, the amount of object can vary but I am only interested in having the ones with queueType: "RANKED_SOLO_5x5" and queueType: "RANKED_TFT" at the start of the array, I wouldn't care about the order of the 3rd and beyond.

Comment: While I do understand what you're saying, I am asking the question because I haven't been able to figure out how begin solving it myself so I don't really have any code. Also I'm not even asking for a functional piece of code, just any pointers on how to begin solving it - pseudocode or explanation would be plenty.

Comment: Does the API return an array with only one object each with one of those `queryType` properties? Will it always return an array with them?

Comment: Still can't sort something we can't see. Don't keep us guessing

Comment: I've added the array which I'm receiving from the GET request. I believe it will always return an array, however, if the user hasn't played any of the queues, I believe that array would be empty.

Comment: I've been thinking about finding the object with queryType: "RANKED_SOLO_5x5" using .find(), removing it from the array and then unshifting it back in. This is what I'm trying to do right now but I'm not sure if it'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm I would use is:

1. Find the index of an element matching a condition
2. Remove and save the object at found index
3. Insert object at correct index at beginning of array

I should note that if there are duplicates that the order may get mixed up at the front of the array as duplicates are getting inserted at either index 0 or 1;

```js
const dataArray = [
  {
    id: 56734567,
    queueType: "RANKED_SOLO_1x1",
  },
  {
    id: 293402,
    queueType: "RANKED_SOLO_1x1",
  },
  {
    id: 85643,
    queueType: "RANKED_TFT",
  },
  {
    id: 446457,
    queueType: "RANKED_SOLO_1x1",
  },
  {
    id: 456235,
    queueType: "RANKED_SOLO_1x1",
  },
  {
    id: 678657,
    queueType: "RANKED_SOLO_1x1",
  },
  {
    id: 42342,
    queueType: "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
  },
  {
    id: 13465346,
    queueType: "RANKED_SOLO_1x1",
  },
  {
    id: 334632,
    queueType: "RANKED_SOLO_1x1",
  },
];

const key0 = "RANKED_SOLO_5x5";
const key1 = "RANKED_TFT";

const sortOrder = [
  key0, // sort key0 to index 0
  key1, // sort key1 to index 1
];

const sortData = (array = [], sortStartOrder = []) => {
  // Higher order find function to take key to search for
  const findByQueueType = key => ({ queueType }) => queueType === key;
  
  // Higher order forEach function to find by key, remove and insert at new index
  const findAndChangeOrder = array => (key, newIndex) => {
    const objectIndex = array.findIndex(findByQueueType(key)); // (1) find index
    if (objectIndex !== -1) {
      const object = array.splice(objectIndex, 1).shift(); // (2) remove object at index if found
      object && array.splice(newIndex, 0, object); // (3) insert at desired index
    }
  };
  
  const newArray = [...array]; // copy in to not mutate passed array

  // For each sortStartOrder entry, use value as search key and index as newIndex
  sortStartOrder.forEach(findAndChangeOrder(newArray));
  
  return newArray;
};

const sortedArray = sortData(dataArray, sortOrder);

console.log(sortedArray);
```

Comment: Sure thing. I tried to leave comments to explain what is going on, but if it's still unclear after a few reads I can always add more.